# How can we display push notifications when app is foreground?

Tags: ios, push-notification, expo

I am using expo notifications. notifications appear very well on android when app is put in the foreground or put in the background.

but it does not appear when app is foreground  on iOS. knowing that I added this command in app.json:

"notification": {
       "iosDisplayInForeground": true
     }
so how could we solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

On iOS, you have to create custom UI for notifications in-app. Only when the app is in background will be displayed by the OS. 
You can catch the push notifications after registering in AppDelegate

```
func userNotificationCenter(
    _ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
    didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
    withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {}
```

Comment: Thank you @User123335511231 I'm using expo/reactnative